# How to understand $E(XY)$ intuitively

Tags: probability, statistics

I have no trouble understanding  $\displaystyle E(X)=\int xf(x)\,dx $ and $\displaystyle E(Y)=\int y f(y)\,dy$

As each $x$ multiplies the corresponding $f(x)$ and we take the integral of it to calculate the sum. (same as $y$)

However when it comes to $E(XY)$, the formula becomes $\displaystyle E(XY) = \iint xy f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dxdy$.

I cant seem to wrap my head around when there are more than one random variable. Is there any way to understand it intuitively?

Comment: $Eh(X,Y)=\int\int h fdxdy$ is the definition for the "average" of possible values that $h(X,Y)$ can take ...

Comment: @Math-fun I understand it yields the average.But how do you interpret the first level integral $ \int h f(x,y)dx$ . I know that for $E(X)$ , the first level integration is the marginal pdf of X which is $f(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have no trouble understanding  $E(X)=\int xf(x)dx $ and $E(Y)=\int y f(y)dy$

Actually, your formulas should read
\begin{align}
E[X] &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty x f_X(x)\,\mathrm dx =
\int_{-\infty}^\infty t f_X(t)\,\mathrm dt \tag{1}\\
E[Y]  &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty y f_Y(y)\,\mathrm dy =
\int_{-\infty}^\infty u f_Y(u)\,\mathrm du\tag{2}
\end{align}
where you need to understand that the $f_X(\cdot)$ in $(1)$ is not
the same as the $f_Y(\cdot)$ in $(2)$, and the second integral in
each case is written to emphasize a fact that is often forgotten by
beginners: *what letter we use to denote the variable of integration
is unimportant: an $X$ does not need to be associated with an $x$ or
a $Y$ with a $y$.*

Turning to the question asked, you are generalizing the wrong definition/formula
when you jump from $(1)$ and $(2)$ to $E(XY) = \int \int xy f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy$. Since you are willing to accept $(1)$ as the *definition* of
$E[X]$, consider a random variable $Z = g(X)$ where $g(\cdot)$ is
some real function of a real variable. What is $E[Z]$?  Well, the
density of $Z$ is $f_Z(z)$ and so applying the definition, we can
immediately say that
$$E[Z] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty z f_Z(z)\,\mathrm dz =
\int_{-\infty}^\infty v f_Z(v)\,\mathrm dv \tag{3}$$
In order to *compute* $E[Z]$ via $(3)$, we need to know $f_Z(z)$
or to first *determine* $f_Z(z)$ from the knowledge that
$Z = g(X)$ and the known $f_X(x)$. Fortunately, the two-step
process of first finding $f_Z(z)$ and then carrying out the
integration in $(3)$ can be combined into a single operation
via a result known as the 
*[Law of the Unconscious Statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician)* (LOTUS for short)
which asserts that the value of $E[Z]$ which is, by *definition*,
the value of the integral on the right side of $(3)$ happens
to equal the value of a different integral:

> $$\text{LOTUS:}\qquad E[Z] = E[g(X)] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)f_X(x)\,\mathrm dx.\tag{4}$$

This is a *theorem* that can be proved (and the proof is not an
easy exercise that can be left to a beginner at this level of explanation to write up for him/herself). The somewhat
pejorative adjective *unconscious* in the name of the theorem 
is because some
people take $(4)$ to be the *definition* of $E[g(X)]$ quite
unconscious of the fact that there already exists a standard 
definition (*viz.* $(3)$) of $E[g(X)]=E[Z]$ and that the assertion
that the right sides of $(3)$ and $(4)$ have the same value is
something that must be proven.

---

With that as prologue, the formula that you should generalize is
$(4)$ and not $(1)$. If $X$ and $Y$ are jointly continuous random
variables with density function $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$, then *gLOTUS* says
that for any real-valued function $h(x,y)$ of two variables, 
the expected value of $Z = h(X,Y)$ happens to equal the value of a double integral, *viz.,*
$$\text{gLOTUS:}~ E[h(X,Y)] 
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(x,y)f_{X,Y}(x,y)
\,\mathrm dx\, \mathrm dy
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(x,y)f_{X,Y}(x,y)
\,\mathrm dy\, \mathrm dx.\tag{5}$$
As special cases of $(5)$, note that if $h(X,Y) = X$ is a
*projection* map, we have that
\begin{align}
E[h(X,Y)] &= E[X]\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty xf_{X,Y}(x,y)
\,\mathrm dy\, \mathrm dx\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty x\cdot \left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y)
\,\mathrm dy\right]\, \mathrm dx\tag{6}\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty x f_X(x)\,\mathrm dx \tag{7}
\end{align}
where the last step follows upon recognizing the inner integral
in $(6)$ as the one that is used to find the *marginal* density $f_X(x)$
of $X$ from the joint density $f_{X,Y})x,y)$, and similarly for
$h(X,Y) = Y$.

Applying gLOTUS to $h(X,Y) = XY$, we have the result that puzzles
you:

$$E[XY] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty xyf_{X,Y}(x,y)
\,\mathrm dy\, \mathrm dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty xyf_{X,Y}(x,y)
\,\mathrm dx\, \mathrm dy\tag{8}$$

Yes, $XY=Z$ is a random variable $Z$ in its own right and the
*definition* of $E[Z] = E[XY]$ is just $(3)$, but gLOTUS allows
us to bypass the step of pre-computing $f_Z(z)$ but use instead
the double integral in $(8)$.

---

In writing the above, I have avoided much of the fine details
in the other answers in favor of a broad-brush approach that
might provide more intuition as to why $(6)$ is correct.

Comment: thanks for such a detailed answer!  You mention that " the expected value of Z=h(X,Y) happens to equal the value of a double integral", can you elaborate a bit more on that?

Comment: @Lzy See the penultimate paragraph in the answer modified as below: Yes, $Z=h(X,Y)$ is a random variable $Z$ in its own right and the definition of $E[Z]$  is just $(3)$, but gLOTUS allows us to bypass the step of pre-computing $f_Z(z) $but use instead the double integral  $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(x,y) f_{X,Y}(x,y)
\,\mathrm dy\, \mathrm dx= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(x,y)f_{X,Y}(x,y)
\,\mathrm dx\, \mathrm dy$$

Comment: I think I get it now. Thanks a lot for the answer. Is there by any chance you can show me where I can find the proof of LOTUS ?

Comment: When can we switch dx and dy without problems?

Answer (score 1):

I guess "intuitively" means without using the term measure, etc?

Firstly, $X$ is a function on a set of event $\Omega$, and  E(X) means $\int_{\Omega}X(\omega)\,{\rm d}P(\omega)$ by definition. $P$ is the probability measure (sorry, just here) we consider. The important thing is that you integrate over $\Omega$.

Now, you wrote $E(X)=\int xf(x)\,{\rm d}x$. In general, for a nice function $h$ you have $E(h(X))=\int h(x)f(x)\,{\rm d}x$ Note that now you are integrating over $\mathbb{R}$, the range of $X$. This is a formula one must show, typically an exercise. (For your future interest: actually one shows $E(h(X))=\int h(x)\,{\rm d}\mu_X(x)$, where ${\rm d}\mu_X(x)$ is the distribution of $X$, and do some discussions on the density $f(x)$)

Consider $E(XY)$. Again we have the formula of the same type, $E(XY)=\int_{\Omega}X(\omega)Y(\omega)\,{\rm d}P(\omega)$.

Finally, we want to obtain the formula for $E(XY)$. It is important to note $XY$ is actually a random variable constructed as $g(X,Y)$ with $g(x,y):=xy$. They are actually a $\mathbb{R}^2$-valued random variable plugged into a deterministic $\mathbb{R}$-valued function. Accordingly, when we want to go to "the world of the range of the random variable", we consider the range of the random variables $(X,Y)$. What we have is
$$
E(g(X,Y))=\int_{\Omega}g(X(\omega),Y(\omega))\,{\rm d}P(\omega)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}g(x,y)f_{XY}(x,y)dxdy,
$$
(if $(X,Y)$ has the density). In particular,
$$
E(XY)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}xyf_{XY}(x,y)dxdy.
$$
The $f_{XY}$ part incorporates the "dependence" of $X,Y$. Again, we are treating $(X,Y)$ as a single $\mathbb{R}^2$-valued random variable, not $X$ and $Y$ separately. It might be helpful to consider the case $X$ and $Y$ are independent. In this case you have $f_{XY}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$, so it simply the integration in each variable.

Comment: Too complicated for an elementary probability student maybe?

Comment: @BCLC Hm...could be. What I tried is to explain which function is defined on what set. Personally, I found the introductory courses in probability so difficult because it typically try to hide too many things. One does not need to know what a measure is etc., but it helped for me $P$ $\mu$, random variables, etc., are defined on what, rather than bizarre explanations such as "random variables are numbers with randomness" etc. Thought clarifying those domain and range and stuff might help, but oh well.

Comment: Lol your answer was picked though

Comment: @BCLC I misclicked.. Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 1):

Please do look at the discrete example in Wikipedia; here is a little more in direct answer to your question.

Consider tossing two fair dice to get realizations of independent random variables $X$ and $Y$. Most games use the sum of the numbers $X + Y$. It is easy to see that $E(X) = E(Y) = 3.5$ and $$E(X+Y) = E(X) + E(Y) = 3.5 + 3.5 = 7.$$

However, it would be possible to invent a game based on $XY$.
Then, using independence, we have
$$E(XY) = \sum_x \sum_y xyf_{X,y}(x,y) = \sum_x \sum_y xyf_X(x)f_Y(y)
= \sum_x xf_X(x)\sum_y yf_Y(y) = E(X)E(Y) = 3.5^2 = 12.25.$$

Here is a simple demo in R based on a million rolls of 2 dice:

```
 m = 10^6;  xy = numeric(m)
 for (i in 1:m) {
   dice = sample(1:6, 2, repl=T)
   xy[i] = prod(dice)}
 mean(xy)
 ## 12.25026
```

For a very similar example where $X$ and $Y$ are not independent,
consider drawing two balls WITHOUT replacement from an urn
with balls numbered from 1 through 6 to get realizations of
random variables $X$ and $Y$. It still makes sense to consider
the random variable $XY$ and its expectation $E(XY).$
There are 30 points in the sample space, each with probability 1/30,
and each with its value of $XY$. Summing all 30 values divided by 1/30, you could get $E(XY).$

```
 Table of values of XY
 X:    1   2   3   4   5   6
 Y
 1:        2   3   4   5   6
 2:    2       6   8  10  12
 3:    3   6      12  15  18
 4:    4   8  12      20  24
 5:    5  10  15  20      30
 6:    6  12  18  24  30
```

Here $E(X) = E(Y) = 3.5$ again, but $E(XY) = 11.67 \ne E(X)E(Y).$
The covariance of $X$ and $Y$ is $Cov(X,Y) = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y) < 0.$
The covariance is negative, roughly speaking because diagonal outcomes, including $(1,1)$
and $(6,6),$ are not possible in sampling without replacement.

An analogous simulation in R, using (default) sampling without replacement.

```
 m = 10^6;  xy = x = y = numeric(m)
 for (i in 1:m) {
   dice = sample(1:6, 2)
   xy[i] = prod(dice) 
   x[i] = dice[1];  y[i] = dice[2] }
 mean(x);  mean(y);  mean(xy);  cov(x,y)
 ##  3.499053    # approx E(X)
 ##  3.500338    # approx E(Y)
 ##  11.66516    # apporx E(XY)
 ##  -0.5827058  # approx Cov(X, Y)
```

Comment: Thanks for showing the examples. Also, when there is only one random variable,the first integral of $E(X) = \int \int x f(x,y)dydx$ would be the marginal pdf of X. Can you explain how I should interpret the first integral of $ E(XY) = \int \int xy f(x,y)dxdy$?

Comment: Yeah this is a great way of looking at things. Random variables can be thought of as payoffs of a game rather than randomly generated numbers following a certain pattern (erm, distribution). XY is simply another payoff and hence E(XY) is the average of that payoff. Calculating that is as stated.

Comment: @Lzy How to interpret $\int x f(x) dx$ ? Sum of each payoff times its probability in a game. Same with xy instead of X and dxdy instead of dx. Xy is the payoff. F(X,y) represents the probability of payoff XY. Sum up the probabilities*payoffs

Comment: @BCLC I meant the first integral $\int xy f(x,y) dx$, what does that mean when you integrate xy multiplies  the joint pdf with respect to x?

Comment: I think I get it now. Thanks for showing me the example where X and Y are dependent.

Comment: @Lzy Oh I understand the confusion. It is not the joint PDF with respect to X. It is the joint PDF of X and Y. A joint PDF is not with respect to just 1 variable. I think you should use subscripts to indicate which PDF is whose. X has its own PDF f_X. Y has its own. XY has its own.